# A riddle for your time (5)

Tags: riddle

```
I'm a fierce weapon chosen by many,
tiny yet so very strong.
I come in different shapes and colors,
but i'm usually quite thin and long.
```

What am i?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you a:

> Pen

Because:

> The pen is mightier than the sword, and the other descriptors fit a pen also.